# Close previously opened application

Tags: photoshop-script

Using Javascript, I do this:

```
var file = File('C:/myapplication.exe');
file.execute();
```

It opens the application. After I open it, I need it closed. I use this:

```
file.close();
```

No luck. What am I doing wrong? I use this in a Photoshop script (`jsx`).

Comment: I don't think this is Javascript. JSX Script seems like another language. You should consider changing your question to attract people with knowledge on the subject with the correct keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which versions are supported but you can

`app.system("Taskkill /F /IM myapplication.exe");`

This is of course windows only.
If this does not work you can write `Taskkill /F /IM myapplication.exe` to a bat file and execute that file.

```
var bat = new File("C:/killmyapp.bat");
bat.open("w");
bat.writeln("Taskkill /F /IM myapplication.exe");
bat.close();
bat.execute();
```

This is basically same as terminating application from windows task manager.